# Is it possible to map Hibernate ResultSetOutput to a pojo

Tags: hibernate

The following code is from hibernate docs

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
ProcedureCall call = session.createStoredProcedureCall( "sp_person_phones");
call.registerParameter(1, Long.class, ParameterMode.IN).bindValue(1L);
call.registerParameter(2, Class.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR);
Output output = call.getOutputs().getCurrent();
List<Object[]> postComments = ( (ResultSetOutput) output ).getResultList();
assertEquals(2, postComments.size());
```

Is it possible to convert the object to pojo by specifying the mapping.

I know it is possible using JPA and @SqlResultSetMapping but looking for a solution using Hibernate API

Answer (score 1):

I did this by manual mapping.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ColumnIndex {
    int value();
}
```

Then using the annotation specify which array index to be mapped

```
@ColumnIndex(value = 4)
private Date eventDate;
```

Also created a util method to do the mapping for any object

```
public static <T> List<T> createBeanList(List<Object[]> propertyValues, Class<T> clazz) {
    List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
    for (Object[] singleObjectProperties : propertyValues) {
        T object;
        try {
            object = clazz.newInstance();
            Field[] fields = object.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field : fields) {
                int fieldIndex = field.getAnnotation(ColumnIndex.class).value();
                set(object, field.getName(), singleObjectProperties[fieldIndex]);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            object = null;
        }
        list.add(object);
    }
    return list;
}

private static void set(Object object, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
    Class<?> clazz = object.getClass();
    try {
        if (fieldValue != null) {
            Field field = clazz.getDeclaredField(fieldName);
            field.setAccessible(true);
            field.set(object, fieldValue);
        }
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        clazz = clazz.getSuperclass();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    }
}
```

Call the utility method

```
List<TCalendar> calendars = ArrayToBeanPropertiesUtil.createBeanList(arrayListResult,
            TCalendar.class);
```